# Azure Web App Deployment Error when using Database.Migrate() on Startup

Tags: azure, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an azure web app and an azure sql instance that I need both to be talking to each other. At run time with the connection string it works great. the only issue is when doing auto "EF Migrations". I used the "context.Database.Migrate()" on startup to do this automatically and on my local computer it worked fine however when deploying the azure web app it would throw an IIS error.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution and I wanted to share with the community in case anyone is having the same issue with their deployments. Make sure to enable "Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server".

[image]